# Regular expression validator postback

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have a regular expression validator. I would like for it to prevent a postback. The first I hit a button then it gives me the error message and no postback is generated but on the second time I click the button the validator is not triggered or doens't prevent postback.

How can I get the regular expression validator to prevent postback on second time? Maybe it is not reading the input box when I don't edit on the second postback?

It may also be that it only prevents the enter button from post back but not the submit button.

I can confirm the first button click doesn't generate a postback but additional ones can. This button uses a commandname.

### In my case, I am trying to prevent the brackets from being submitted. I do not want to turn off the validaterequest.

Update it seems to be due to the fact I've placed this code in container server control. The odd behavior doesn't occur when the control is placed directly in the page. Evaluating what this means.

Comment: They work. You do not need to do anything special. If it's not working in your case, you should post your code so people can help you

Comment: Yes, it works fine. But on the second time I hit the button then it generates a post back but not on first time. I don't want it to generate a postback when invalid ever.